# Scala Slick and nested case classes

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I'm quite new to Scala and need to use slick to build a table mapping for these case classes.

I can do it for a simple case class but the nesting and option parameters are leaving me confused how to do this?

```
case class Info(fullName: Option[String], dn: Option[String], manager: Option[String], title: Option[String], group: Option[String], sid: Option[String])

case class User(username: String, RiskScore: Float, averageRiskScore: Float, lastSessionId: String, lastActivityTime: Long, info: Info)
```

I need to end up with a simple table which contains all of the combined parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your nested case class definitions, a bidirectional mapping for the `*` projection similar to the following should work:

```
case class Info(fullName: Option[String], dn: Option[String], manager: Option[String], title: Option[String], group: Option[String], sid: Option[String])

case class User(username: String, riskScore: Float, averageRiskScore: Float, lastSessionId: String, lastActivityTime: Long, info: Info)

class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {

  def username = column[String]("user_name")
  def riskScore = column[Float]("risk_score")
  def averageRiskScore = column[Float]("average_risk_score")
  def lastSessionId = column[String]("last_session_id")
  def lastActivityTime = column[Long]("last_acitivity_time")

  def fullName = column[Option[String]]("full_name", O.Default(None))
  def dn = column[Option[String]]("dn", O.Default(None))
  def manager = column[Option[String]]("manager", O.Default(None))
  def title = column[Option[String]]("title", O.Default(None))
  def group = column[Option[String]]("group", O.Default(None))
  def sid = column[Option[String]]("sid", O.Default(None))

  def * = (
      username, riskScore, averageRiskScore, lastSessionId, lastActivityTime, (
        fullName, dn, manager, title, group, sid
      )
    ).shaped <> (
      { case (username, riskScore, averageRiskScore, lastSessionId, lastActivityTime, info) =>
          User(username, riskScore, averageRiskScore, lastSessionId, lastActivityTime, Info.tupled.apply(info))
      },
      { u: User =>
          def f(i: Info) = Info.unapply(i).get
          Some((u.username, u.riskScore, u.averageRiskScore, u.lastSessionId, u.lastActivityTime, f(u.info)))
      }
    )
}
```

Here is a great relevant [Slick article](https://lihaimei.wordpress.com/2016/03/30/slick-1-fix-more-than-22-columns-case/) you might find useful.

Comment: I get errors when I try to compile:
Error:(210, 23) stable identifier required, but Users.this.RiskScore found.
    { case (username, RiskScore, averageRiskScore, lastSessionId, lastActivityTime, info) =>
Error:(211, 105) one more argument than can be applied to method apply: (username: String, RiskScore: Float, averageRiskScore: Float, lastSessionId: String, lastActivityTime: Long, info: gailey.org.Info)gailey.org.User in object User
      User(id, username, RiskScore, averageRiskScore, lastSessionId, lastActivityTime, Info.tupled.apply(info))

Comment: And...
polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [R]slick.lifted.MappedProjection[R,(String, Float, Float, String, Long, (Option[String], Option[String], Option[String], Option[String], Option[String], Option[String]))]
 required: slick.lifted.ProvenShape[gailey.org.User]
  ).shaped <> (
type mismatch;
 found   : slick.lifted.MappedProjection[Nothing,(String, Float, Float, String, Long, (Option[String], Option[String], Option[String], Option[String], Option[String], Option[String]))]
 required: slick.lifted.ProvenShape[gailey.org.User]
  ).shaped <> (

Comment: @Steve Gailey, my bad, there was an extra comma between the first two fields.  Answer revised.

Comment: Yup, found the extra comma and removed that but get the errors above after that. If I could get it working I could start to figure out how it works but I can't even compile :-( Unfortunately the error messages mean nothing to me :-(

Comment: @Steve Gailey, apparently the compilation failure stems from Slick not viewing `RiskScore` a valid field name, subsequently leading to mismatch in argument size/type, ...  Things look good once it's renamed to `riskScore`.  The revised code above appears to compile fine.